# Arrays in bash shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script to count the total in an array
# Define the name of the file
#
fname=names.txt

# Read in the contact details from the keyboard
echo "Please enter the following contact details:"
echo
echo "Given name: \c"
read name
echo " value: \c"
read value
# Write the details to the text file
echo $name:$value >> $fname
```

I'm trying to code something in bash scripting, I have a txt file and I entered the following names on it e.g

```
lex +7.5
creg +5.3
xondr/xonde +1.5
gloria-1
lex +7.5
gloria -1
creg +5.3
xondr/xonde +1.5
lex +7.5
#and so on
```

I want a code or a loop that when I run the program it should show the names of that are on the txt file and show there total,if lex appears 7 times and gloria 3 times it will show lex 52.5 gloria-3 etc. I don't know if you get my idea...

Comment: well, your shebang indicates `sh`, not `bash`

Comment: Does it _really_ have to be a shell script? I'm not trolling, just asking.

Comment: NOt sure what you are asking.

Comment: If this is homework for school, you should tag it as such. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '{people[$1] += $2} END {for (person in people) 
{ printf("%s %10.2f\n",person,people[person])}}' test.txt
```

Comment: Yes "it works", but you spawn a useless process. awk read files itself ;)

Comment: im trying to add this code you gave me but its not working im new to bash,may you help me with a sample script or where to put it in my code..thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
$ awk '{x[$1] += $2} END {for( i in x) print i, x[i]}' input-file
```

Comment: Le mort saisit le vif.  I <3 awk on occasion.

Comment: Tiens un Français. Mais je comprend pas pour autant l'expression.

Comment: @sputnick: Je pense que l'idée est quelque chose comme 'Le Roi est mort, vive le Roi !'

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A names
declare name num

#sum
while IFS=" " read name num; do
    names[$name]=$( bc <<< "${names[$name]:-0}$num" )
done

#print
for name in ${!names[@]}; do
    echo "$name: ${names[$name]}"
done
```

Something like this? Depends on the two fields being separated by space and the numbers being prepended with + or - though.